# Multiple submit on form php

Tags: php, forms, submit

On my form I have 3 submit,I want to know the best way to handle these buttons because the default action is the same form:

```
<form method="POST" action="file_where_form_is.php">
      Name:<input type='text' name='name'>
      <input type='submit' name='add' value='Add Names' ONCLICK='window.location.href="file_where_form_is.php">
      <input type='submit'name='Preview'value='Preview'ONCLICK='window.location.href="file_where_form_is.php">
      <input type='submit' name='submit'value='Submit' ONCLICK='window.location.href="send.php">                                           

</form>
```

This not seems to work completely,just the 2 first work and for the last submit does nothing(with name='submit')
Any suggestions?

Comment: what are you expecting to happen / trying to do?

Comment: I add some names in a table,after I preview what names I added,and then I add In Database(send.php)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found in header part add something like this:

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      header("location: somefile.php");
 }
 elseif(isset($_POST['Preview'])){
       header("location: anotherfile.php");
 }
 elseif(isset($_POST['add'])){
       header("location: anotheronefile.php");
 }
```